# Show when a Chef cookbook version changed on a node using knife

Tags: chef, knife

The infrastructure that I am working on uses Chef environments to manage the cookbook versions that are converged to nodes.

While I can use knife to check what cookbook versions are available, and what cookbook versions are deployed in nodes or across an environment, is there any way I can use knife to see when a node switched from the previous version of a cookbook to the current version?

Answer (score 0):

No, this data is not stored by Chef. You would need to check something else like your Chef Automate run history data or source control history.